# Проблема с forEach в массиве js

Tags: javascript, foreach

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу заменить повторение кода(который закоментировал).

```
module.exports = function(Product) {
  /*Product.disableRemoteMethod('createChangeStream', true);    
  Product.disableRemoteMethod('upsert', true);
  Product.disableRemoteMethod('upsert', true);
  Product.disableRemoteMethod('updateAll', true);
  Product.disableRemoteMethod('replaceOrCreate', true);
  Product.disableRemoteMethod('replaceById', true);
  Product.disableRemoteMethod('exists', true);
  Product.disableRemoteMethod('count', true);
  Product.disableRemoteMethod('findOne', true);*/

  var array = ['createChangeStream', 'upsert', 'updateAll', 'replaceOrCreate', 'replaceById', 'exists', 'count', 'findOne'];

  array.forEach(function(item, i, array) {
    Product.disableRemoteMethod( i + item + array );
  });
};
```

Comment: вставь код текстом

Comment: ну и творишь какой-то ужас, надо было просто `item` и `true` передавать, а не складывать его с `i` и `array`

Comment: Я только начинающий вот и творю "ужас")

Comment: `Product.disableRemoteMethod(item, true);`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто сравнить закомментированные вызовы с тем что внутри цикла

```
Product.disableRemoteMethod('upsert', true);
Product.disableRemoteMethod('replaceById', true);

Product.disableRemoteMethod( i + item + array );
```

Можно заметить два отличия: внутри цикла в функцию передается *один* параметр, вместо двух. Передаваться должно *только* значение из массива куда, как раз и вынесены изменяющиеся параметры

```
Product.disableRemoteMethod( item, true );
```